# Working with Multiple Checkboxes in PDF Form - using PDF-LIB npm

Tags: javascript, npm, pdf-lib.js

[image: This is the image for the textboxes.]

I have two checkboxes in my PDF. They are "Ja" & "Nei". But when I use `const fields = form.getFields()` this property to get checkbox names im getting only `name===> PDFCheckBox: dodJaNei`

So how can I use two checkboxes?

```
const checkBoxxx = form.getCheckBox('dodJaNei')
checkBoxxx.check()
```

In above logic it checks the first checkbox but not the second check box.

[image]

So how to to implement the the logic for these two checkboxes?

Comment: Make sure that your checkboxes have different names.  Adobe Acrobat has an option, "Prepare a form", located in the "All tools" menu.  Clicking on this will reveal all of the form field names.  If you see "dodJaNein#0" and "dodJaNein#1", rename them so that PDF-LIB can recognize these fields.  PDF-LIB has some issues when fields are named exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

here's a similar situtaion i went through in my code where i had multiple check boxes and user can select multiple check boxes from it. after selecting, the user submits the form and the selected checkboxes fields were present in the submit function (you can look into shadcn form checkboxes for more detail for it) and then i basically loop over it and get the checkbox and select them
where **generalLiabilities** is that array.

```
if (generalLiabilities.length > 0)
    generalLiabilities.forEach((item) => {
      const checkbox = form.getCheckBox(item);
      if (checkbox) {
        checkbox.check();
      }
    });
```

let me know if that solution works